# Jasper plugin in Grails: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, grails, jasper-plugin

I am trying generate report in doc format using jasper plugin, exception is generated at:

```
JasperReportDef report = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), result)
```

line in my controller

Exception:

```
could not initialize proxy - no Session. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at   org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2170)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1332)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1317)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1218)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1194)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1544)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
at com.cvsurgeon.DownloadCVController$_closure3.doCall(DownloadCVController.groovy:563)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have googled and found some alternate but not works in my case like:
    [How to use jasperreports subreports with grails jasper plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730777/how-to-use-jasperreports-subreports-with-grails-jasper-plugin/7304156#7304156)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is that you are filling the report with data that are consisted of domain objects.

Some properties of these domain objects are lazy-loaded at the time when the report is generated, but Session is not available hence the error.

I see three possible solutions:

1. Do a call of jasperService.buildReportDefinition in a service instead of controller - session should be available there.
2. Instead of using domain objects to fill the report, copy necessary data to a DTO and use it.
3. Identify which properties are lazily-loaded and make them eagerly-loaded instead - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#fetching